# Error importing .tex file into Lyx

Tags: errors, lyx, sharelatex

I am using ShareLaTex to work collaboratively. The main.tex file compiles perfectly on the website, without any red warnings. However, when I try to open **main.tex** in the downloaded project folder using Lyx I get:

[image]

In Lyx, I did **File -> Import -> LaTeX(plain)**

This has only been hapening until two modified versions ago of the document. Two versions ago, I could open the main.tex in Lyx without major issues (some formatting problems but ok... nothing major). Any idea of what could be happening?

Windows 10 - 64bit, Lyx 2.2.2

Answer (score 1):

The problem to this was I apperently add to figures badly defined in the main.tex file. They compiled ok in ShareLaTex, but failed to compile (giving the error above) in Lyx.